# OpenNebula - Bridge VM NIC with Host NIC - take Ip from LAN DCHP

Tags: kvm, opennebula

I hope you are doing well,
I start using OpenNebula here, I deploy a basic setup one Opennebula fronend in centos 8
another server as OpenNebula Node,
I download an image from marketplace it's centos image, Then I create a network Under Network >> Virual Network. Bridge it with ens33 (ens3 is the physical interface of my node) in order to give VM access to LAN,
he is my Node net

```
[centos@host1 ~]$ ifconfig
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.60  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether 00:0c:29:68:26:2b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 679155  bytes 994474147 (948.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 41914  bytes 3220552 (3.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6  bytes 672 (672.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6  bytes 672 (672.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:89:84:b1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

once I create a VM and attach it to the bridge network I create already, i get status Failed with the bellow log :

```
Sat May 1 03:50:25 2021 [Z0][VM][I]: New state is ACTIVE
Sat May 1 03:50:25 2021 [Z0][VM][I]: New LCM state is PROLOG
Sat May 1 03:50:38 2021 [Z0][VM][I]: New LCM state is BOOT
Sat May 1 03:50:38 2021 [Z0][VMM][I]: Generating deployment file: /var/lib/one/vms/14/deployment.0
Sat May 1 03:50:39 2021 [Z0][VMM][I]: Successfully execute transfer manager driver operation: tm_context.
Sat May 1 03:50:40 2021 [Z0][VMM][I]: Command execution fail: cat << EOT | /var/tmp/one/vnm/bridge/pre
Sat May 1 03:50:40 2021 [Z0][VMM][E]: pre: Command "sudo ip link add name ens33 type bridge " failed.
Sat May 1 03:50:40 2021 [Z0][VMM][E]: pre: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sat May 1 03:50:40 2021 [Z0][VMM][E]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sat May 1 03:50:40 2021 [Z0][VMM][E]:
Sat May 1 03:50:40 2021 [Z0][VMM][I]: ExitCode: 2
Sat May 1 03:50:40 2021 [Z0][VMM][I]: Failed to execute network driver operation: pre.
Sat May 1 03:50:40 2021 [Z0][VMM][E]: Error deploying virtual machine: bridge: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sat May 1 03:50:40 2021 [Z0][VM][I]: New LCM state is BOOT_FAILURE
```

can anyone please explain to me what's wrong here, Im familiar with vsphere esxi/vcenter, I want just to create a VMNetwork and attach it to the node physical NIC then attach the VM to this VMNetwork in order to give it LAN access, on VMware side it's easy simple but with OpenNebula Im not sure how it's work

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using a physical interface instead of using a bridge. If you would like to use bridge networking, you need to create a bridge or let OpenNebula create it for you.

Let me know if this answers your issue, if not, feel free to submit your query on OpenNebula Forum - https://forum.opennebula.io/. :)

Comment: Hello Shivang, Thank you for your help, Just a quick one how can i let opennebula create a bridge for me ?

Comment: Hi XCCIE, Happy to help! :) 

In regards to your doubt, you just need to put a bridge name like br0 and OpenNebula will create one, if it doesn't exist.